# How do you move text vertically relative to its line-height?

Tags: html, css

I have a small text element next to a div and they are centered in a flex container. When they are this short, it becomes apparent that the text is slightly offset upwards by a few pixels. How would you fix this without using margin-top on the text and not removing any of the existing styles below? Is there a way to move text relative to its line-height?

```css
.container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 2rem;
border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;
 font-size: 1rem;
 margin: 0;
}

.box {
 height: 1rem;
 width: 3rem;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <h2>N</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: There are ways to move the text. Keep in mind that the N appears to be offset upwards only because fonts include letters like `j`, `y`, `g` that will fill the empty space below as well as characters like `|` and ``` and others that fill the top. Just be careful.

Comment: I understand, but I won't be using letters like j/y/g, so the text will look offset

Comment: Again, just be careful. You can add negative `margin-bottom` to the `h2` tag to move it down.

Answer (score -1):

use baseline alignment instead of center then consider a pseudo element to simulate the center alignment:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: red;
}

.container:before {
  content:"";
  height: 1.5rem; /* this value is not generic and need to be updated based on your case*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <h2>N</h2>
</div>
```

Or another idea where you adjust the alignment inside the title using another hack with pseudo element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
}
h2:before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: super;
}

.box {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <h2>N</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but that's basically the same concept as adding margin to the text except instead of margin, you're adding a pseudo element. I was hoping maybe there'd be a css property that could be applied to the text elements themselves instead of their container.

Comment: @Iamok added another idea ;)

Comment: @Iamok did you check my last attempt?

Comment: Yeah, but it still uses a pseudo element which is just more complicated than adding a margin-top to the text element. I am looking for a more optimal solution, not just different solutions.

Comment: @Iamok and how would you describe the *optimal* solution? In my second solution I am not using any explicit value. I simply added `vertical-align: super;` to a pseudo element (only one property). I guess you would agree that you need at least *one* extra property added to your code to change the behavior of your code.

Comment: Optimal meaning a simple 1 or 2 liner. `margin-top` seems to be the simplest and more straight-forward solution, but I just hoped that maybe there was a CSS property I was unaware of.